# put application version in shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, installation

I'm trying to put the application version number in my shorcut (when you got to start -> all programs you see myapp 1.0.1). I tried to add [version] and [Productversion] to the shortcut name in the setup project but that doesn't work.

Regards,
Stijn

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not a good practice:

[Avoid putting a version number in a program name unless that is how users normally refer to your program.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511447.aspx#names)

It's better to put the [ProductVersion] somewhere in the WelocmeText label in the 'User Interface' view.
Or even better use a decent MSI authoring tools such as [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) which allows you customizing anything that VS installers won't.